# How to set the environmental variables when starting vscode-remote-containers from within vscode-remote-WSL?

Tags: vscode-remote

To build my remote environment I need several environmental variables to be set (they are used in the docker-compose file). These are set in my ZSH environment, so running docker-compose build works as expected from the terminal. However these variables are not available when running the `reopen in container` command. How/where can I set the variables that will be available to vscode when running docker-compose build? Note that I am running vscode-remote-containers from within vscode-remote-WSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the vscode logs it is apparent it calls `wsl -d Ubuntu -e /bin/sh ..... docker-compose up` to build the container, thus not taking into account any environmental variables set in `.bashrc` or otherwise. I solved it by putting required variables in the [WSLENV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop) like so: `WSLENV=REQUIRED_VAR/u:ANOTHER_REQUIRED_VAR/u`
Then they are available for docker-compose when run from wsl.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `devcontainer.json`:

```
"containerEnv": {
    "MY_CONTAINER_VAR": "some-value-here",
    "MY_CONTAINER_VAR2": "${localEnv:SOME_LOCAL_VAR}"
},
"remoteEnv": {
    "PATH": "${containerEnv:PATH}:/some/other/path",
    "MY_REMOTE_VARIABLE": "some-other-value-here",
    "MY_REMOTE_VARIABLE2": "${localEnv:SOME_LOCAL_VAR}"
}
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-advanced

Comment: This concerns setting variables inside the container after it has been built, not during the build step.